# pg_query_params error inserting defaults or using functions

Tags: php, postgresql

pg_query_params seems not working as expected:

this works:

```
INSERT INTO users (username,password,secretcode) VALUES 'test',crypt(:password,gen_salt(md5)), 'DEFAULT'
```

secretcode field have a default generated value

This doesn't works:

```
pg_query_params($Db, 'INSERT INTO users (username,password,secretcode) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', array ($USR,crypt($PWD,gen_salt(md5)),'DEFAULT');
```

password field contains the string 'crypt($PWD,gen_salt(md5))'

secretcode field contains 'DEFAULT' string

Is this the correct behavior or a bug ?

Thanks

Dan Perez

Comment: Aside from you pg problem you should read up about password storage: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Of course, this is only a sample to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are *designed* to send exactly the literal text you wrote. The whole point is that they don't execute functions or otherwise get interpreted as SQL syntax.

`DEFAULT` is a keyword. That's not what you're supplying, you're sending the *text* `'DEFAULT'`.

Similarly, you're sending the *text* `crypt($PWD,gen_salt(md5))` to PostgreSQL.

If you want to insert using a query you can do that, but you must modify the SQL. E.g.

```
pg_query_params(
  $Db,
  'INSERT INTO users (username,password,secretcode) VALUES ($1, crypt($2, gen_salt('md5')), DEFAULT)', array ($USR,$PWD)
);
```

As you can see, you can put arbitrary expressions in the `VALUES` clause, as well as keywords like `DEFAULT` or `NEW`. You can't pass them as query parameters.

I'd really like it if there were "special" client values that you could pass, magic constants that were interpreted as keywords like `DEFAULT`. It doesn't work that way, though; the `DEFAULT` keyword is interpreted at parse/plan time, not parameter binding time.

Also, you must quote the hash type in `gen_salt` - `'md5'` not just `md5`.

Finally - `crypt` is not an acceptable way to hash a password.

Comment: >>As you can see, you can put arbitrary expressions in the VALUES clause...

That's' the trick ! Thanks !